# Make [pf-datatable] a synonym of [primefaces-datatable]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are a lot of questions about the PrimeFaces datatable which are tagged with the generic [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) tag while a specific [pf-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pf-datatable) tag exists.

It is probably overlooked because other PrimeFaces tags start with `primefaces`. Having a `primefaces-datatable` tag hopefully will improve use of the tag.

Comment: how about creating a `primefaces-datatable` tag and make `pf-datatable` a synonym of it?

Comment: I'd say less is more, but yeah, I could do that

Comment: I don't know if renaming is even possible (guess not) but making a synonym would have the desired effect and oeople could still search for `pf-datatable` which would then be redirected to the new tag

Comment: Are datatables in primefaces a completely different concept as compared to datatables in general? If not, then using the general datatables tag along with primefaces tag should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there were only about 50 questions, I've gone ahead and merge into [primefaces-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces-datatable)

```
updating post history, 57 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 50 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 50 rows affected
destroying 'pf-datatable': [pf-datatable] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 60
tag remapping of [primefaces-datatable] and [pf-datatable] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym pf-datatable -> primefaces-datatable was approved!
```